# Restful web service hosted in IIS 7 not handling data contract members

Tags: web-services, iis-7, c#-3.0, datacontract, datamember

I have a requirement to create a simple HTTP C# restful web service hosted in IIS 7 that can support a POST from a callout and the format of the POST data does not seem to be handled properly. The requirement for the data member names is that they have a dash in them, such as custom-1. My problem is that the datamembers names who are custom-10 or higher are only giving me null for data. custom-1 thru custom-9 are fine.

If anyone can help, I appreciate it!!!

Here is the required format of the POST data:

```
 <person-search-request xmlns="someurl"> 
    <person>
        <custom-1 />
        <custom-2 />
        <custom-3 />
        <custom-4 />
        <custom-5 />
        <custom-6 />
        <custom-7 />
        <custom-8 />
        <custom-9 />
        <custom-10 />
        <custom-11 />
        <custom-12 />
        <custom-13 />
        <custom-14 />
        <custom-15 />
        <custom-16 />
        <custom-17 />
        <custom-18 />
        <custom-19 />
        <custom-20 />
      </person>
     </person-search-request>
```

My Web service data contract looks like this:

```
    [CollectionDataContract(Name = "person-search-request", Namespace="")]
    public class PersonsRequest : List<Person>
    { }

    [CollectionDataContract(Name = "person-search-response", Namespace="")]
    public class PersonsResponse : List<Person>
    { }

    [DataContract(Name = "person", Namespace = "")]
    public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
            Custom14 = String.Empty;
            Custom13 = String.Empty;
            Custom15 = String.Empty;
            Custom16 = String.Empty;
            Custom17 = String.Empty;
            Custom18 = String.Empty;
            Custom19 = String.Empty;
            Custom20 = String.Empty;
            Custom7 = String.Empty;
            Custom8 = String.Empty;
            Custom9 = String.Empty;
            Custom1 = String.Empty;
            Custom10 = String.Empty;
            Custom11 = String.Empty;
            Custom12 = String.Empty;
            Custom3 = String.Empty;
            Custom4 = String.Empty;
            Custom5 = String.Empty;
            Custom6 = String.Empty;
        }


        [DataMember(Name = "custom-14")]
        public string Custom14 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-7")]
        public string Custom7 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-8")]
        public string Custom8 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-9")]
        public string Custom9 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-13")]
        public string Custom13 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-15")]
        public string Custom15 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-16")]
        public string Custom16 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-17")]
        public string Custom17 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-18")]
        public string Custom18 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-19")]
        public string Custom19 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-20")]
        public string Custom20 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-10")]
        public string Custom10 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-11")]
        public string Custom11 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-12")]
        public string Custom12 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-1")]
        public string Custom1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-2")]
        public string Custom2 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-3")]
        public string Custom3 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-4")]
        public string Custom4 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-5")]
        public string Custom5 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-6")]
        public string Custom6 { get; set; }
        /// <summary>


    }
```

My Service endpoint is setup like this:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true), AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed), ServiceContract]
public partial class Service
{

     [WebHelp(Comment = "Person POST")]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "person/v1.0/fetch", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    [OperationContract]
    public PersonsResponse FetchPerson(PersonsRequest request)
    {
            ....
     }
```

}

The Post data looks like this (using Fiddler to test):

```
    <person-search-request> 
    <person>
        <custom-1>1</custom-1>
        <custom-2>2</custom-2>
        <custom-3>3</custom-3>
        <custom-4>4</custom-4>
        <custom-5>5</custom-5>
        <custom-6>6</custom-6>
        <custom-7>7</custom-7>
        <custom-8>8</custom-8>
        <custom-9>9</custom-9>
        <custom-10>10</custom-10>
        <custom-11>11</custom-11>
        <custom-12>12</custom-12>
        <custom-13>13</custom-13>
        <custom-14>14</custom-14>
        <custom-15 />
        <custom-16 />
        <custom-17 />
        <custom-18 />
        <custom-19 />
        <custom-20 />
     </person>
</person-search-request>
```

The data comes into the endpoint with nulls in the 10-20 custom tags. Anyone know why??? :(

This is what I see when I debug from the request object passed into the method.

```
     Custom1    "1" string
    Custom10    null    string
    Custom11    null    string
    Custom12    null    string
    Custom13    null    string
    Custom14    null    string
    Custom15    null    string
    Custom16    null    string
    Custom17    null    string
    Custom18    null    string
    Custom19    null    string
    Custom2 "2" string
    Custom20  null  string
    Custom3 "3" string
    Custom4 "4" string
    Custom5 "5" string
    Custom6 "6" string
    Custom7 "7" string
    Custom8 "8" string
    Custom9 "9" string
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using the order attribute. Still acting unpredictable. If anyone else has a better explanation that would be appreciated!!!

Anyways, here is the fix (there are other not important members starting using 1 & 2 slot):

```
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-1", Order = 3)]
        public string Unused1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-2", Order = 4)]
        public string Unused2 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-3", Order = 5)]
        public string Unused3 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-4", Order = 6)]
        public string Unused4 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-5", Order = 7)]
        public string Unused5 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-6", Order = 9)]
        public string Unused6 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-7", Order = 10)]
        public string License { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-8", Order = 11)]
        public string LicenseState { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-9", Order = 12)]
        public string Tax { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-10", Order = 13)]
        public string Unused10 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-11", Order = 14)]
        public string Unused11 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-12", Order = 15)]
        public string Unused12 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-13", Order = 16)]
        public string ProfDesignation { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = @"custom-14", Order = 17)]
        public string NPI { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "custom-15", Order = 18)]
        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "custom-16", Order = 19)]
        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "custom-17", Order = 20)]
        public string Address3 { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "custom-18", Order = 21)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "custom-19", Order = 22)]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "custom-20", Order = 23)]
        public string Zip { get; set; }
```

Comment: I wanted to add a link to another place where I am having this discussion in case others need this information.

[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/1fbfda63-9b26-4005-b77a-37473d4ece85/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/1fbfda63-9b26-4005-b77a-37473d4ece85/)